# Single Page MVC Navigation

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am building a single page scrolling MVC website that needs to be able to move to different sections of the page when a link is clicked, preferably without refreshing the page, just scrolling to said location on click event. My question is whether this would be some JavaScript or whether I can do so with just some regular and some C#.

Comment: The following link will move the user's screen so they see the matching `div` `<a href="#idName">` `<div id="idName">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alexei Darmin said in a comment try to use #id's in divs and refer to those id's in your links, that's the tipical way to do it and you shouldn't have any problem unless you load the content dinamically, in that case you should implement a method in your angular control that force the async load to, at least, that point and move the user to it.

Answer (score -1):

For single Page application, Angular Js is more efficient and you can achieve the performance also. And also if you use this script, your app is like Web Api,you can control your resolutions for different devices.

Angular Js is best , so you can use in your app. hope it will useful to you. Thanks.

just refer its useful to you :

[Link1](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)

[Link2](http://www.awwwards.com/practical-uses-of-angularjs-create-a-single-page-application-spa-or-a-website-menu-in-an-instant.html)